# HP Envy 5541: Attention Required but no information given

Tags: windows-10, printer, hp-envy

I use an HP Envy 5541 wirelessly for printing from my Windows 10 laptop.

Sometimes when I print, the item is added to the print queue but no printing takes place. The printer status according to Windows is *Attention Required*. There is no information given on the printer display.

*I have also noticed that the number of documents pending when I hover over the printer icon in the system tray is often inaccurate, stating that there are more documents in the queue that there really are (but never fewer).*

My fix for this, which has worked several times, is to run the Troubleshooter available from 'Devices and Printers'. The Troubleshooter runs and reports that it could not find the fault. However, printing **magically** starts *before the Troubleshooter has finished.*

[image]

*When this fix does not work, I briefly press the power button the printer to 'wake it up' (the display illuminates) and then re-run the above wizard - printing then commences.*

What could be going on and is there a way to stop the situation arising where I need to run the Troubleshooter to unblock printing?

*NB: I have the latest HP ENVY 5540 All-in-One Printer series Firmware Update EN5540_R1831A.exe downloaded from support.hp.com*

*NB2: I have run the HP Print and Scan Doctor tool from the HP website. It erroneously claims the printer is out of paper, which is untrue and disagrees with the printer's own display. Ultimately the Print and Scan Doctor signals that it is unable to resolve the issue and recommends re-installing the printer software. I have already done this, and so am no further forward.*

*NB3: Restarting the print spooler service does not correct the issue*

Comment: Wow, 1000 views. There must be a lot of trouble of this sort out there!

Comment: Wow, 2500 views. Still a lot of hassle with these wireless HP printers! I've persevered with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It was an issue with using an old-fashioned WiFi extender!

Both my laptop and wireless printer are in a converted garage and so I was using a BT Dual-Band Wi-Fi Extender 610.

When I switched from this to a BT Smart Hub with integrated Wi-Fi disc (which extends the Wi-Fi) then the issues with the printer disappeared.

One difference seems to be that the old Dual-Band extender has a different name to sign in to, while to new disc extends the signal seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a wireless printer connection, your situation is that the printer is offline. After the printer is offline, the default printer becomes an offline printer. We try to turn off the network card sleep and printer sleep.

If it does not work above, we try the following method:

1. Print Website Pages With an Alternative Browser
2. Disable Protected Mode in Internet Explorer
3. Update Drivers
4. Install the latest updates
5. Restart the Print Spooler service
6. Make sure that your printer is properly installed or reinstall your printer.

For details we can refer to the article:
[Fix: “The printer requires your attention” error](https://windowsreport.com/the-printer-requires-your-attention/)